# .SQL files opening as blank in Oracle SQL Developer

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am attempting to open SQL files from an external folder in Oracle SQL Developer.

When I drag and drop or double click the files, they open in a new SQL worksheet but the file will show as blank. I can manually copy/paste the file in but I am concerned this will harm the integrity of the file (missing a section to paste in).

I have suspicions this relates to the jdk path as I recently moved it. But I can still manually run SQL statements without issue.

Any ideas?

Comment: Weird...is it possible that there some encoding issue going on here?  Do the files only appear blank in SQL Developer?  What happens if you open them in Notepad++, or some other IDE?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen That's what's strange, they open fine in other environments (I'm currently copy/pasting from notepad++) it's only in SQL Developer.

Comment: Let's nail this down.  Create a new SQL script, enter some dummy code, save and close.  When you reopen that same file in Developer, what happens?

Comment: Interesting point. When the file is saved in SQL Developer It can be opened and show as it would normally. Including importing a new SQL statement copy/pasting and saving. However saving without making edits will blank out the .sql file

Comment: I have no idea what is causing this.  Maybe you could try reinstalling SQL Developer as a last resort, making sure to point to the newly moved JDK path.

Comment: Is it possible to edit the JDK path? It's odd because everything else functions as expected. I wouldn't think the program could function without it.

Comment: Version of Windows,SQL Developer, and Java? What kind of file and file extension? What does an external folder mean? Are you dragging from windows explorer or the View - Files panel?

Comment: I don't know SQL Developer very well, but if it is running off your system Java, then it's probably looking at `JAVA_HOME`.

Comment: @thatjeffsmith Windows 10 Home 64-bit, Oracle SQL developer 11g, Java JDK 8 windows x64. .sql file extension. I am dragging from windows explorer.

Comment: You have an ancient copy of SQLDev it sounds like...go to OTN and download version 18.2.

Comment: Good point, I will try that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was caused by using an older version of SQL developer and the latest versions of JDK and Oracle DB Express Edition. Once I updated the SQL Developer to version 18.2 the problem was solved.